# C++ error: "undefined reference to cnt(int) collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status

Tags: c++, undefined-reference, exitstatus

When I compile this C program, I get an error:

```
In function `main': maxcount.cpp:(.text+0x63): undefined reference to `cnt(int)'

collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
```

What does it mean?  Here is the code:

```
#include<iostream>
using namespace std;
int cnt(int);
int main()
{
  int x[30],i,j,q;
  cout<<"enter x[i]";
  for(i=0;i<7;i++)
  {
    cin>>x[i];
  }
  q = cnt(x[30]);
}
int cnt(int x[30])
{
  int i,j;
  int max=x[0];
  int count=0;
  for(i=0;i<7;i++)
  {
    if(x[i]>max)
    {
      max=x[i];
    }
    else
    {
      max=x[0];
    }
  }
  for(i=0;i<7;i++)
  {
    if(max==x[i])
    {
      count++;
    }
  }
  cout<<count;
  return 0;
}
```

Comment: You're universally using arrays wrongly. It looks like you think the name of the array is `x[30]`, but it isn't; its name is `x`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It means that it can not find a definition for `int cnt(int);`, which `main()` uses and you forward declare.

Instead, you define:

```
int cnt(int x[30]) { ... }
```

These are two different signatures.  One takes an integer argument, and the other takes an array of integers.

Additionally, this statement is incorrect:

```
q=cnt(x[30]);
```

This takes the *31st* element at index 30 from the `x` array.  However, `x` is only declared to be of size 30.  Since you are using `x` as an array inside your function, you probably just want to change your forward declaration to:

```
int cnt(int[30]);
```

And then invoke it like this:

```
q = cnt(x);
```

Answer (score 1):

```
int cnt(int x[30]) { ... }
```

is *not* the same as:

```
int cnt(int x) { ... }
```

While you declare a prototype for the function taking a single integer, you never *define* such a function. Instead you define one taking an array.

You need to figure out whether you want to pass the array or an element of the array. The call:

```
q=cnt(x[30]);
```

attempts to pass the 31st element of the array (which doesn't exist by the way). I suspect (since you're dereferencing `x` in the function) you probably wanted to just pass `x`, which is the entire array (or, more correctly, the address of the first element of said array).